# How do IP addresses work on a VPS? Routing a domain name to Node.JS

Tags: node.js, hosting, vps

This is an absolute newb question. But I'm buying my first VPS for the reason that I want to install and start creating applications in Node.JS.

I can't visualise in my mind how the server works and where all of the applications such as Apache, Node.JS and PHP sit. I'm so used to a GUI.

I want www.mydomain.com to point to node.JS on my server, let's say Node is listening to port 8080. Now I know that HTTP defaults to port 80 of the IP address, so I can't use that. How do I set the domain up to resolve at www.mydomain.com:8080 - I read this wasn't possible...

My brain is melting.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You just point the domain to your ip address as you normally do. The issue you will have it that HTTP default to port 80, so either you manually add the port at the end of the host to get to the page or you setup Apache to proxy specific urls to 8080, which gets some of your Node stuff appearing to work under 80.

If you aren't using Apache for anything you can also have your Node app bind to port 80. You will probably need to setup authbind or something to give your node app permission to bind to port < 1024.

Comment: Not sure if this is still true, but I recall hearing that having node apps bind directly to port 80 was a bad idea. Ryan Dahl always recommended putting node behind apache or nginx. That was a year ago when I last heard that though, so best practices might have changed (although I doubt it).

Comment: I've read that too. But I also read that putting node behind apache or nginx will affect websockets. I am definitely confused as to how someone is supposed to build an application in node and have it accessible by a domain without manually entering a port number :S